# Install mysqlclient for Django in MacOs

Tags: django-mysql

I try to run "pip3 install mysqlclient" on macos for an app in django and it gives me this error.

I'm using a venv virtual environment, the python version used is 3.10.5

```
pip3 install mysqlclient
Collecting mysqlclient
  Using cached mysqlclient-2.1.1.tar.gz (88 kB)
  Preparing metadata (setup.py) ... error
  error: subprocess-exited-with-error
  
  × python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
  │ exit code: 1
  ╰─> [16 lines of output]
      /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
      /bin/sh: mariadb_config: command not found
      /bin/sh: mysql_config: command not found
      Traceback (most recent call last):
        File "<string>", line 2, in <module>
        File "<pip-setuptools-caller>", line 34, in <module>
        File "/private/var/folders/p3/dxl5kg797mz8th2cvxq_5g0w0000gn/T/pip-install-zl914sek/mysqlclient_ea5a67ae479943158a52dad5dfef7756/setup.py", line 15, in <module>
          metadata, options = get_config()
        File "/private/var/folders/p3/dxl5kg797mz8th2cvxq_5g0w0000gn/T/pip-install-zl914sek/mysqlclient_ea5a67ae479943158a52dad5dfef7756/setup_posix.py", line 70, in get_config
          libs = mysql_config("libs")
        File "/private/var/folders/p3/dxl5kg797mz8th2cvxq_5g0w0000gn/T/pip-install-zl914sek/mysqlclient_ea5a67ae479943158a52dad5dfef7756/setup_posix.py", line 31, in mysql_config
          raise OSError("{} not found".format(_mysql_config_path))
      OSError: mysql_config not found
      mysql_config --version
      mariadb_config --version
      mysql_config --libs
      [end of output]
  
  note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

note: This is an issue with the package mentioned above, not pip.
hint: See above for details.
```